# Check if anyelement ISNULL [ Postgresql ]

Tags: postgresql, polymorphic-functions

I am Trying to implement the access function 'isnull' in postgresql this function takes as a parameter an expression and the function returns true if null has been passed, or false if it is not null. I know postgres has the 'IS NULL' and 'NOT NULL' keywords bu I keep getting polymorphic errors when passing either a string or a null value itself to the function as they are both unknown types.

This method has to be done using a function.

What I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnull( anyelement ) RETURNS anyelement as $$
    BEGIN
        IF $1 IS NULL THEN RETURN TRUE;
        ELSE RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;
    END
    $$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: And why don't you want to use `IS NULL`?

Comment: Additionally to the function `isnull( anyelement )` create another one declared as `isnull( text )` with the same body. It should to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define these two functions, it will work for all cases:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnull(anyelement) RETURNS boolean
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS 'SELECT $1 IS NULL';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnull(unknown) RETURNS boolean
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS 'SELECT $1::text IS NULL';
```

The additional advantage is that SQL functions like these can be inlined.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isnull( anyelement ) RETURNS boolean as $$
BEGIN
    RETURN $1 IS NULL;
END
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Test:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test(a int, b int);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, null), (2, null);
SELECT isnull(a), isnull(b) FROM test;
```

Gives:

```
 isnull | isnull
--------+--------
 f      | t
 f      | t
```

Comment: This works through the console, yes, but It probably won't work though prepared statements in C or Java. PostgreSQL has a very stupid bug when it comes to nulls, but to them it's "working as intended".

Comment: Every null must have a data type, or their corresponding internal data type must have a registered converter function that takes the Oid for Unknown type, before it can be checked if it's a null. If that transformation doesn't exist (because maybe xml isn't the same as integer), then you can't convert an SQL NULL of one type to a NULL of the other. And not all types have conversion from unknown.

Comment: Try running `SELECT ? IS NULL` as a prepared statement in JDBC, or `PREPARE is_a_null AS SELECT $1 IS NULL` through the console. The problem is there, and it's most annoying in inserts and updates.

Comment: This answer will fail for `SELECT isnull(NULL)`